# Pronunciation of "zounds?"

Tags: pronunciation, early-modern-english

I came across the sentence "Fortunately their are a variety of different offerings out there with zounds of features." Disregarding the misuse of "zounds," how would Elizabeth I have pronounced the word? To rhyme with "God's wounds?" Or otherwise?

Comment: -1 for (a) asking a question that can be answered by any number of dictionaries and (b) complaining about a downvote.

Comment: Back when I was doing SCA and Renaissance Faires (a *very* long time ago), I was told the "authentic" way to pronounce it was *zwoonds*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes most sense to me that zounds should rhyme with wounds. When you take two words and combine them and then contract them, they retain their pronunciation.

*couldn't* isn't pronounced *cowdn't*

*doesn't* isn't pronounced *dow-znt*

*bosun* isn't pronounced *bossun*

Nevertheless, it seems both pronunciations are ok: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zounds, and /zaʊndz/ appears to be more prevalent: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/zounds

English is weird, eh?

EDIT: See Snumpy's answer. It started off as rhyming with *wounds* and changed during the Great Vowel Shift to rhyme with *sounds*

Answer (score 4):

If it's anything like the exclamation, it would rhyme with *sounds*.

EDIT: It apparently has been affected by the [Great Vowel Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Vowel_Shift).  Maybe someone else can provide a link to exactly how the 16th-17th century version of *ou* would have been pronounced.

Comment: your wikipedia link has it:
*Middle English [uː] was diphthongised in most environments to [ʊu], and this was followed by [əʊ], and then Modern English [aʊ] (as in mouse) in the eighteenth century.*

Comment: @gpr I guess I was hoping for an audio of the *[əʊ]* diphthong... but I searched through the IPA verbs enough to get an idea of how it might sound.

Comment: The 'ou' was originally Norman-French orthography for 'u'. *Thou* was said as *thu* from (OE þu). *Wound* (the injury) was spelled *wund*. We still hav this split ... *you*, *group* ... but *about* and *house*. So we can thank the N-F scribes for screwing up a lot of spelling and causing befuddling spellings that still haunt us.

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that back when the contaction of "God's wounds" came into being and common use, the Great Vowel Shift had yet to happen in English.  "Wounds" back then rhymed with "bounds" and "sounds" as pronounced today.  Therefore, "zounds" also rhymed with "sounds" and "bounds" and still should today.  The change in pronunciation for a "wound" in human or animal flesh occurred for that rather commonplace word, but the pronunciation of "zounds" did not change.  There are a number of people who say it should be pronounced "zoonds" because "wounds" used to be pronounced "woonds," but I think they're being pedantic.  On the rare occasion that I might say "zounds" for humorous effect -- since it is a rather outmoded expletive that now sounds quaint -- I'm going to continue to say it so it rhymes with "sounds" and "bounds."

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but based on gpr's comment above, I think you may have the Great Vowel Shift backwards – all the words used to sound like _wounds,_ but _sounds_ and _zounds_ shifted away from it.

Comment: Your Great Vowel Shift is definitely backwards one way or another. **1.** _Wound_ had a simple /uː/ before the GVS, and so did _bound_: they rhymed, but sounded (roughly) like _wound_ does today, not like _bound_. _Sound_ always had a diphthong, probably /ou/ before the GVS, and besides that, it didn’t normally have a d before the GVS, so it didn’t rhyme with the other two at all. **2.** _Zounds_ most likely did not really exist yet before the GVS (first OED attestation is 1593, at which point /uː/ had already split to /əʊ/). It would have been nice if it had, though, because it would →

Comment: → be quite regular (as regular as anything involving the GVS can be) for _wound_ /wuːnd/ to remain /wund/, while _zound_ /zuːnd/ became /zaʊnd/. Long /uː/ regularly gave /ʊu/, then /əʊ/, and finally /aʊ/, but not after a glide (/w/ or /j/)—so _wound_, _youth_, _you_, etc. still have /uː/, not /aʊ/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I don't know if you saw my most recent posts in chat? I searched a digitized version of the Canterbury Tales and found evidence that "soun" (sound) belonged to the same rhyme group in Chaucer's dialect as "toun" (town). It seems to me that this was probably a simple /uː/ at Chaucer's time, and not /ou/. Do you have any evidence for "soun" historically having a /ou/ diphthong in English?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how "zounds" can rhyme with "wounds" unless you are pronouncing it

> zoo-nds

Which just seems silly.

So, I would pronounce it so it rhymes with ***sounds***.

Comment: ...That's actually how I pronounce it. I've heard others do so as well. Granted I'm a very silly person, but I don't think I'm superlatively so. And in case you're wondering, I do use it relatively often. It works wonderfully when I'm mocking my friends. :)

Answer (score 0):

Zounds should be a rhyme for Sounds, unless the context is suggesting to another way.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think it should rhyme with "wounds" since it's a contraction of "God's wounds" referring to Jesus's wounds on the cross.

Back in the time when it was used, people would swear on God's body parts rather than his name, thus avoiding breaking the Third Commandment, "Do not take the Lord's name in vain." Essentially, it's an archaic "Holy crap!"

So it would make much more sense for it to rhyme with "wounds," since that's the word it's derived from. However, pronunciation of certain words was wonky back then, and besides, gpr already established that both pronunciations *can* be correct, so the argument is irrelevent.

Why, then, did I comment? Because I like to impress people with my ability to properly follow links and use Google. And because people kept saying it should rhyme with "sounds" and I wanted to argue with them, because that's what I do.

Answer (score -1):

People mention the great vowel shift - yay! Some may have noticed there's another vowel shift happening at the moment on the streets of London.
Anyway, zounds is indeed an abbreviation of "God's wounds" and rhymes with it. What gets overlooked is that 'wounds' rhymed with 'sounds' before the great vowel shift, much the way 'wind' rhymed with 'kind'.

Comment: _Wound_ and _sound_ did not rhyme before the Great Vowel Shift. _Soun(d)_ always had a diphthong, while _wound_ had a short monophthongal /u/. Also _wind_ and _kind_ still rhyme, if you use the verb _wind_ as your basis.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Sound always had a diphthong? Can you explain that? I thought "ou" was already monophthongal /u/ in French by the time of Middle English, which explains why the French digraph "ou" was used to represent native English /uː/ in words like "ground" or "down." The ancestor of "sound" is apparently Anglo-Norman "soun"; wouldn't this have been pronounced /sun/ in French and /suːn/ in Middle English?

Comment: @sumelic No, it was (and is) _son_ in French—the diphthongisation was sporadic and irregular, but it happened in Anglo-Norman or English, not in French. The word never had /u/, neither in French nor in English.

Comment: It's "son" in Modern French, but dictionaries of English I look at confirm "soun" as the source of the English word. "noun senses 1 to 5 Middle English soun, from Anglo-Norman French soun (noun), suner (verb), from Latin sonus." http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sound_1?q=sound

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: whoops, I forgot to ping you on that last comment. Anyway, I don't know if "ou" was maybe a diphthong in Anglo-Norman, but the evidence I can find seems to suggest it was just /u/.

Comment: @sumelic I honestly don’t know where they’re getting those particular forms from. Anglo-Norman probably had _soun_ as a variant at least, but Old and Middle French didn’t. [FEW](https://apps.atilf.fr/lecteurFEW/lire/170/195) notes specifically that there is only sporadic diphthongisation in French (while in Spanish and Italian, it’s general). More importantly, though, homorganic lengthening would be necessary to get a long /uː/ in the first place, and homorganic lengthening was no longer productive by the time _so(u/w)n_ was borrowed, and certainly not by the time it gained its /d/.

Comment: So absent any other indications, we would expect Anglo-Norman /sun/ ⟨so(u)n⟩ to stay _sun_ and rhyme with the celestial body in Modern English, or (with its new /d/) to have become simply _sund_. Old English _*sund_ would have given _*sūnd_, which would have given _sound_ straightforwardly—but the OE form was _sōn_ (which I think was lost entirely); OE _sund_ is ‘sound’ in the nautical sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26562/discussion-between-sumelic-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).