# What is the name of a word like "shite"?

Tags: offensive-language

Whilst watching the 3rd Test match between England and Australia, from Edgbaston, this week, the Barmy Army of England fans were singing as ever (the Australians are not terrace-singers in quite the same way as the English). And among their repertoire the little jingle intended to needle the Australian bowler Mitchell Johnson, and put him off his stride:

*He bowls to the left,
He bowls to the right,
But, Mitchell Johnson,
His bowling is shite*.

When I looked it up I was amazed to find that ***shite*** has an entry in the OED with examples of its use from as early as 1733.

Intended as a word that takes some but not all of the offence out of using *shit*, it is also undoubtedly helpful to football and cricket fans when composing their rhyming ditties.

One can think of other words *crikey*, *bloody wars* or *bloody Hilda* (avoiding *by our lady Mary*),etc. What is the name given to a word intended to be a swear word- but not quite?

> Etymology:  Variant of shit n., probably resulting from the influence
>   of forms of shit v. with a long vowel, although there could also have
>   been an (unattested) inherited form in Old English with a long vowel
>   (deriving from the e-grade of the same Germanic base); compare Middle
>   Low German schīt, schīte faeces, filth, Middle High German schīze
>   diarrhoea (German Scheiße faeces), Old Icelandic skítr faeces. The
>   word occurs earliest regionally (chiefly in Ireland (where it is the
>   usual form) and Scotland), and subsequently in colloquial English as a
>   jocular or quasi-euphemistic variant of shit . For possible older
>   attestation in place names see the etymological note at shit n.
>
> regional (chiefly Sc. and Irish English) and coarse slang (chiefly
>   Brit., Austral., and N.Z.).  A. n.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-offensive substitute for a swear word](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/non-offensive-substitute-for-a-swear-word)

Comment: The answer to the question you seem to intend is a 'minced oath' (as in the suggested duplicate). But *shite* is not such; as a variant of *shit*, it is precisely as offensive, and is 'valuable to football fans' only as providing another rhyme.  I would not want any learner to think the term inoffensive

Comment: @TimLymington That was not my intention.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The term is ***minced oath***. That is, the profanity has been cut up a little, and mixed with other stuff.

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minced_oath):

> *A **minced oath** is a euphemistic expression formed by misspelling, mispronouncing, or replacing a part of a profane, blasphemous, or taboo term to reduce the original term's objectionable characteristics. Some examples include gosh, darn, dang, and heck.*

I remember being impressed when I was taught this term as a kid, not so much for the term itself, but because we were given the example *Zounds!*.

"*Zounds*," you ask, "*a minced oath? Whatever for?*"

*God's wounds*. I know, weird, right?

Comment: How is *Zounds* weird? It's pronounced *zo̅o̅nds* not *zownds*.

Comment: Not sure I'd really call _shite_ minced, though. To me, it's just a slightly rustic (or Irish, inasmuch as the two are distinct outside Ireland) variant, like _feck_ or _eejit_ instead of ‘fuck’ and ‘idiot’. The difference between these and actual minced oaths, I'd say, is that mincing an oath includes replacing part of the oath with something that it never alternates with otherwise (like /l/ with /k/ in _hell -> heck_), while these are just dialectal pronunciations that display at least reasonably commonly found alternants (/dʒ/ instead of /d(i)j/, for example, or /iː/ instead of /ɪ/).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Tell that to Shaggy and Scooby-do (ok, ok, they said *zoinks*). Anyway, what I found weird/surprising  was the etymology of *zounds*, not its pronunciation.

Comment: To me, "shite" is actually _more_ offensive than "shit". Perhaps it's because the vowel is more forward and projected? "Shit" is a constricted kind of utterance, good for personal frustration. But "shite" can be (and is) hurled to the world.

Comment: @Andrew and Dan: Don’t forget [this question about the pronunciation of _zounds_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24026/pronunciation-of-zounds). If _zounds_ predates the Great Vowel Shift, its regular pronunciation is /zaʊndz/ (like _sounds_), and /zuːndz/ (like _wounds_) is influenced by its etymological relationship with _wounds_; if it postdates the Great Vowel Shift, /zuːndz/ is the regular pronunciation, and /zaʊndz/ must have come about as a spelling pronunciation because it **looks** like _sounds_ etc. in writing.

Comment: @DanBron Well done. the earliest OED reference to *minced oath* is 1654, interestingly during the *Protectorate* of Oliver Cromwell. As swearing was undoubtedly an offence under the Puritan leader, as was the theatre, and other entertainment, minced oaths perhaps were essential to survival. *1654   in Trans. Banffshire Field Club (1908–9) 96   The elders of Dunbennand..[ought to] abstain from minched oaths*.

Comment: @DanBron Though the Wiki article carries no reference to Cromwell, there is reference to Puritans in the reign of Elizabeth I. *Late Elizabethan drama contains a profusion of minced oaths, probably due to Puritan opposition to swearing. Seven new minced oaths are first recorded between 1598 and 1602, including 'sblood for By God's blood from Shakespeare, 'slight for God's light from Ben Jonson, and 'snails for By God's nails from the historian John Hayward. Swearing on stage was officially banned by the Act to Restraine Abuses of Players in 1606, and a general ban on swearing followed in 1623*

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I wonder if the 'minced' in this case has more to do with the "walk with an affected delicacy or fastidiousness, typically with short quick steps" than the "cut up in small pieces" meaning.

Comment: @Margana: Wild guess: You're British.  In America, it's the other way around.  "Shite" doesn't sound as bad to us because it's a quirky British word.

Comment: @Kevin nope Margana is maybe just contrary, in the UK shite is generally considered a lesser form of shit.

Answer (score 2):

Well one word is  **euphemism**.

> euphemism
>
> /ˈjuːfəmɪz(ə)m/
>
> noun: euphemism; plural noun: euphemisms
>
> a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered
>   to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or
>   embarrassing. "the jargon has given us ‘downsizing’ as a euphemism for
>   cuts"
>
> synonyms: polite term, substitute, mild alternative, indirect term,
>   understatement, underplaying, softening, politeness, genteelism, coy
>   term  "‘professional foul’ is just a euphemism for cheating"

**EDIT**

But I prefer Dan Bron's 'minced oath' in this context.